# Laravel query a Model over one of it's related models

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I have a model that has a related object. This data could have been stored in the same model, but it resides in a different database which is only used to look it up and attach it to my model.

Say I have the following structure:
`BaseModel->AttachedModel`

I would like to get all attached models with some criteria, but via the BaseModel since there are a few more objects attached to the BaseModel I need.

I tried to achieve this using `BaseModel::where('attachedmodel.id', 100)->get()` (since this looks like the `with()` method I hoped it would work)

In this case I'm trying to get all BaseModels where there is a AttachedModel with id 100. But this fails.

Can this be done, or should I use a raw query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The with() method will eager load the relation and not filter any results. What you need is a whereHas query, which filters the results based on criteria on the related model.

```
$lookingForId = 100;
Basemodel::whereHas('attachedmodels', function ($query) use ($lookingForId) {
  $query->where('id', '=', $lookingForId);
})->get();
```

whereHas() first parameter (in above code it is 'attachedmodels'), should be the name of the relation, as defined into your Model class

Comment: I believe you are correct. The with-construction @noodles_ftw suggested didn't actually filter the results. I'm trying to get your suggestion to work but it's taking some time. MySQL isn't quite approving with us so far ;) A +1 for your effort and contribution. Welcome to SO btw!

Comment: This should be the correct answer. I'll accept yours. For me it's not working because the attached model uses a different driver (MSSQL) and while the query looks correct it's not working. This, I believe, is due to the fact that one single query tries to incorporate two database connections and drivers.

Comment: What @noodles_ftw said is a constraint on eager loading the relationships of the base model. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah I know about them. Nifty feature ;)

Comment: It's going to be a heavily populated table with a live database connection to another production system. Therefore that's not a suitable option but thanks for the suggestion. I've decided to downgraded the filter option only to search for an ID which is also a businessknown ID.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BaseModel::with(['attachedmodel' => function($query) {
    $query->where('id', '100');
}])->get()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The 100 input variable is of course dynamic. I've added `use($input)` after `function($query)` and before `{` in order to pass in the variable. Also I'd like to mention that it is neccessary to explictly attach all other needed related objects since Eloquent only returns the relationship models that are defined in the `with` method. Thanks! +1 and accepted.

Comment: I figured it would be a variable, but I went with the data you provided. You're welcome :).